# TFS-Git - Restrict visibility by branches

Tags: git, tfs

I'm doing the initial configuration of some Git repositories on a TFS 2017 Update 1 RTM server. And I'm looking for a way to be able to restrict the visibility of specific branches to specific user groups. An example:

I have two teams of developers D1 and D2, both work on the same repository and have visibility of the main branches (develop, master and release). But I need the possibility to create a branch of work, say B1, on which the D1 can work normally, but D2 does not have read permissions to it.

From what I have been able to see, you can only restrict the visibility / reading at the repository level, but is there any possibility of restricting visibility at the branch level?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visibility can't be set for a specific branch, the option is only available at the repository level.
That being said, if you go in the "manage repositories" section, you can set the "contribute" option to a specific group.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks anyway. The problem is that "contribute" allows push and block, but is not related to visibility.

Comment: Aziris is correct, visibility can't be set for a specific branch, the option is only available at the repository level. You could submit a uservoice at website below for your requirement: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/category/145257-dashboards-and-reporting.